# Scrollable frame will not render all items in it Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, scroll, tkinter

I am working on a program where there is a scrollable frame that will be containing a large quantity of items. But with my app it does not render all of them. Can someone possibly tell me why? And how I can fix it?

Code:

```
#700x650

from Tkinter import *
import ttk

class itemLoad:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def item(self):
        items = "Video File,Image File,None,King King"

        return items

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH)

        self.loadItem = itemLoad()

        self.one = None

        self.create_widgets()
        self.loadItems()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.mainFrame = Frame(self, width=700, height=650)
        self.mainFrame.pack_propagate(False)
        self.mainFrame.pack()

        self.menu = Frame(self.mainFrame, width=150, height=650, bg="Gray92")
        self.menu.pack_propagate(False)
        self.menu.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.itemMenu = Frame(self.mainFrame, width=550, height=650)
        self.itemMenu.pack_propagate(False)
        self.itemMenu.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.vScroller = ttk.Scrollbar(self.itemMenu, orient=VERTICAL)
        self.vScroller.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.itemMenu, bd=0, width=534, highlightthickness=0, yscrollcommand=self.vScroller.set)
        self.canvas.pack_propagate(False)
        self.canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
        self.vScroller.config(command=self.canvas.yview)

        self.innerFrame = Frame(self.canvas, width=550, height=650, bg="Pink")
        self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self.innerFrame, anchor=NW)

        def update(event):
            self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

        self.innerFrame.bind("<Configure>", update)

        self.spacer = Frame(self.mainFrame, bg="Gray")
        self.spacer.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

        frame = Frame(self.menu, bg="Gray92")
        frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        high = Frame(frame, bg="Gray92", width=10)
        high.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

        self.bu1 = Label(frame, font=("Calibri", 14), text=" Main Folder", width=12, anchor=W, bg="Gray92")
        self.bu1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, ipadx=10, ipady=10)

        frame2 = Frame(self.menu, bg="Gray92")
        frame2.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        high2 = Frame(frame2, bg="Gray92", width=10)
        high2.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

        self.bu2 = Label(frame2, font=("Calibri", 14), text=" Favorited", width=12, anchor=W, bg="Gray92")
        self.bu2.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, ipadx=10, ipady=10)

        frame3 = Frame(self.menu, bg="Gray92")
        frame3.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        high3 = Frame(frame3, bg="Gray92", width=10)
        high3.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

        self.bu3 = Label(frame3, font=("Calibri", 14), text=" Trash Can", width=12, anchor=W, bg="Gray92")
        self.bu3.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, ipadx=10, ipady=10)

        frame4 = Frame(self.menu, bg="Gray92")
        frame4.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

        high4 = Frame(frame4, bg="Gray92", width=10)
        high4.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

        self.bu4 = Label(frame4, font=("Calibri", 14), text=" Log Out", width=12, anchor=W, bg="Gray92")
        self.bu4.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, ipadx=10, ipady=10)

        def hover(event):
            widg = event.widget

            items = widg.winfo_children()

            if items[1].cget("text") == self.one:
                pass
            else:
                items[0].config(bg="Gray85")
            items[1].config(bg="Gray85")

        def unHover(event):
            widg = event.widget

            text = None

            items = widg.winfo_children()

            if items[1].cget("text") == self.one:
                pass
            else:
                items[0].config(bg="Gray92")
            items[1].config(bg="Gray92")

        def clicked(event):
            widg = event.widget
            par = widg.winfo_parent()
            par = self.menu._nametowidget(par)

            for item in self.menu.winfo_children():
                items = item.winfo_children()

                items[0].config(bg="Gray92")

            for item in par.winfo_children():
                try:
                    self.one = item.cget("text")
                except:
                    item.config(bg="lightBlue")

        frame.bind("<Enter>", hover)
        frame2.bind("<Enter>", hover)
        frame3.bind("<Enter>", hover)
        frame4.bind("<Enter>", hover)
        frame.bind("<Leave>", unHover)
        frame2.bind("<Leave>", unHover)
        frame3.bind("<Leave>", unHover)
        frame4.bind("<Leave>", unHover)
        high.bind("<Button-1>", clicked)
        self.bu1.bind("<Button-1>", clicked)
        high2.bind("<Button-1>", clicked)
        self.bu2.bind("<Button-1>", clicked)
        high3.bind("<Button-1>", clicked)
        self.bu3.bind("<Button-1>", clicked)
        high4.bind("<Button-1>", clicked)
        self.bu4.bind("<Button-1>", clicked)

    def loadItems(self):
        theItems = self.loadItem.item()

        for i in range(0, 500):
            none = Frame(self.innerFrame, width=200, height=500, bg="red")
            none.pack_propagate(False)
            none.pack(side=TOP, padx=10, pady=10)

            let = Label(none, text=i)
            let.pack(side=TOP)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x650")
root.resizable(0,0)

app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're exceeding the limits of the tkinter canvas. The frame you're trying to scroll is 250,000 pixels tall. I doubt the canvas can handle that.

When I make all of your inner widgets considerably smaller your code works fine.

Comment: yeah I made them smaller and I did get significantly more widgets in it but I was mainly testing to see the limit of it. Is there a way to by pass this limit?